# Clustered column chart for single cell data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a column plot for my single cell analysis that has 2 sample types, a normal and PDAC. I want to show, the percentage of different cell types per sample type.

How do I go about determining the percent of each cell type in each condition and then go about plotting the column plot? Also, is it possible to determine the SD from the dataset and add it?

**dput(head(all@meta.data))**

```
structure(list(orig.ident = c("PDAC", "PDAC", "PDAC", "PDAC", 
"PDAC", "PDAC"), nCount_RNA = c(7945, 7616, 7849, 5499, 853, 
1039), nFeature_RNA = c(2497L, 2272L, 2303L, 2229L, 509L, 588L
), percent.mt = c(2.63058527375708, 3.7421218487395, 4.9433048796025, 
0.490998363338789, 0.234466588511137, 0.192492781520693), RNA_snn_res.0.5 = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19"), class = "factor"), seurat_clusters = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19"), class = "factor"), S.Score = c(0.0171539298241524, 
-0.00599651468836135, 0.011058574403656, -0.0424413740104151, 
0.03549521163095, -0.0243347616753686), G2M.Score = c(-0.0591387992008088, 
0.0253275642795205, -0.0512402869839816, -0.0239076248512967, 
-0.0263164126515597, -0.0339086517371782), Phase = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("G1", "G2M", "S"), class = "factor"), 
    old.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", 
    "T Cell", "Endothelial", "Tumor", "Stellate", "Macrophage", 
    "B Cell", "Mast Cell", "Acinar", "Endocrine", "Exocrine"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("PDAC_AAACCCAGTCGGCTAC-1", 
"PDAC_AAACGAAGTCCAGGTC-1", "PDAC_AAAGAACAGCAAGTGC-1", "PDAC_AAAGAACAGGATGAGA-1", 
"PDAC_AAAGTGACATCCGTTC-1", "PDAC_AACAACCAGGAAGTAG-1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can start with `prop.table()` to get the percentages.

Comment: @haci So I would do `prop.table(all@meta.data)`

Comment: `prop.table()` requires a table as input so you can try something like `prop.table(table(object@meta.data$column1, object@meta.data$column2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `table()` and `prop.table()` to calculate the number and proportions of your cell types with respect to tissue of origin.

`prop.table()` requires a table as input so you can start with something like `prop.table(table(object@meta.data$cell_type, object@meta.data$tissue)`. This will create an objet of class `table`.

Next step is to create a data frame with `as.data.frame(your_table_object)` and then to convert it to "long format", for example with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. You can feed these data in long format to `ggplot()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you have `dplyr` and `ggplot` installed, you could try something like (if a is your data.frame)

```
a %>% 
dplyr::group_by(orig.ident, old.ident) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(count  = n()) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=orig.ident, y=count)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(group=old.ident), position='dodge')
```